# Programming Android in C

Tags: android

Is there any way to program an android device without using java? I have programmed in assembly, basic, c ,c ++, c#,Forth and fortran. I only want to port an application I have written in c,c++,c#. I use it to learn a new language. I cant even get an image to load from an xml file.

Comment: Instead of trying the NDK you should probably just post questions asking why your image wont load and other things you're having trouble with.  I doubt that using the NDK will be easier than the Android SDK.

Answer (score 4):

You might have a look at the Android NDK : http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You must use Java in the main part of the application with your user interface.

[edit]
Android's interface between Java and C is strange and harder to use than the one in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some C coding using the NDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). But I doubt that you can do everything there.

Answer (score 0):

I love Eclipse and Java D:

Anyways,

Take a look at the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)